# SQLite loses data (insert, update) after restarting app

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

When I update my data:

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
            {
                var query = conn.Table<kursy>().Where(k => k.kurs == kursStaryRubel).SingleOrDefault();
                query.data = kursAktualnyData;
                query.kurs = kursAktualnyRubel;

                conn.Update(query);
            }
```

Everything works fine. The data is updated. But when I close and open my application again, this data has old value - it's not updated. I'm using the same database, it is not recreated. Why is it happening?

My DB_PATH:

`public static string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "test.db");`

My database file has property `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Copy if Newer`

Comment: @Steve, thanks for your replay. `public static string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "test.db");`. My `test.db` database is created only once - when the database doesn't exists in my StorageFile of my WP. Then my app always use this database which is in my WP. So I don't know why it loses data after restarting...

Comment: No, I haven't noticed the tag WinPhone, that answer doesn't apply to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

Unconsciously database was replaced at the start. The problem was that I created database in the `Storage` , not in the `IsolatedStorage`. I do not know if I understand this correct, but when it was created in Storage, the database was created in the memory of the application, and that's why database expires when I close app. But when I create database in IsolatedStorage it is permanently placed in the phone memory. And then even if I turn off the application, the database remained, because it was created in the phone memory, not in the application memory.